# Is wireless network sutabile for VoIP services?

Tags: cisco, wireless, design, voip, architecture

We are moving our HQ to a new building, I am responsible for designing the network and the data center, I was thinking to make it all wireless, but what about the voice services, can we get a good VoIP and video conferanceing services specially that the wireless is a half duplex only connection, also I am looking to Cisco solutions for the VoIP because we getting a new one, is there any better company do VoIP for wireless ?

Comment: Going all wireless?  Plan to quadruple your helpdesk staff.

Comment: Why exactly do you think we will have more issues?

Comment: See the answers in the possible duplicate of [Is a wireless only network (for end users) a viable option?](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/is-a-wireless-only-network-for-end-users-a-viable-option)

Comment: Thanks, I already read these answers, this is not what I am looking for, my question specific regarding the VoIP over wireless.

Comment: You might consider using all softphones via your laptop which connect back to a central provider. There are several manufacturers which will let you use softphones in lieu of a physical phone.

Answer (score 1):

Recommendations on which manufacturer to use are off-topic here.  But I can tell you from experience that you can reliably do VoWLAN.

But the performance of the wireless network is more critical when you're using VoIP. You will need a denser AP deployment than for just data.  You need to make sure they survey takes VoIP into account.  Pay close attention to AP placement and expected user density.

You will also spend more time testing and tweaking your clients (wireless phones, etc), especially if you're using phones from a different manufacturer.